# Upload to firebase: TypeError: uploadTask.on is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

I am doing a react POC for upload image to firebase. [I have followed the firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on)

[Also referred to this blog post from dev.to](https://dev.to/itnext/how-to-do-image-upload-with-firebase-in-react-cpj)

react version: `"^16.13.1",`
firebase version: `"^7.15.5"`,

For `uploadTask.on()`, I tried two approaches.

1. put everything inside it as it is ie. not using `next, error and complete` keywords.
2. put the code separately into each one of them and pass them inside uploadTask.on()

I am getting the error: **`TypeError: uploadTask.on is not a function`**

I have referred the documentation many times now, but sure where I am going wrong.

[image: Edit react-firebase-image-upload]

`imageUpload component code`

```
import { storage } from "../firebase/index";


const ImageUpload = () => {
  const initImgState = { imgUrl: "" };
  const [imgAsFile, setImgAsFile] = useState("");
  const [imgAsUrl, setImgAsUrl] = useState(initImgState);
  const [progress, setProgess] = useState(0);

  const handleImgAsFile = (e) => {
    console.log("triggering handle image as file");
    const image = e.target.files[0];
    setImgAsFile((imgFile) => image);
  };

  const next = (snapShot) => {
    // takes the snapShot of each step of the process
    console.log(snapShot);
    const progress = Math.round(
      (snapShot.bytesTransferred / snapShot.totalBytes) * 100
    );
    setProgess(progress);
  };
  // error handling
  const error = (error) => {
    //catches the errors
    console.log(error);
  };
  const complete = () => {
    // gets the functions from storage refences the image storage in firebase by the children
    // gets the download url then sets the image from firebase as the value for the imgUrl key:
    storage
      .ref("images")
      .child(imgAsFile.name)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((fireBaseUrl) => {
        setImgAsUrl((prevObject) => ({
          ...prevObject,
          imgUrl: fireBaseUrl,
        }));
      });
  };

  const handleCloudUpload = (e) => {
    console.log("triggering handle upload");
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("starting to upload");
    // checkin if the file is an image
    if (imgAsFile === "") {
      console.error(`not an image, the image file is a ${typeof imgAsFile}`);
      return <p>`not an image, the image file is a ${typeof imgAsFile}`</p>;
    }
    const uploadTask = () =>
      storage.ref(`/images/${imgAsFile.name}`).put(imgAsFile);
    // initiates upload to cloudserver ie firebase
    uploadTask.on(storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, {
      next: next,
      error: error,
      complete: complete,
    });
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Form onSubmit={handleCloudUpload}>
        <Form.Group role="form">
          <ProgressBar animated now={progress} max="100" />
          <Form.File id="exampleFormControlFile1" onChange={handleImgAsFile} />
          <Button variant="outline-primary" type="submit">
            Upload File into Firbase
          </Button>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
      <p>Preview</p>
      <Image
        src={imgAsUrl.imgUrl || "http://via.placeholder.com/1024x1024"}
        fluid
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

`firebase initialize code`

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY",
  authDomain: "react-image-upload-and-c-bbd0f.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://react-image-upload-and-c-bbd0f.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "react-image-upload-and-c-bbd0f",
  storageBucket: "react-image-upload-and-c-bbd0f.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "73677178427",
  appId: "1:73677178427:web:149704e87714eff275fe1e",
  measurementId: "G-89WQ7XLYQK",
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

const storage = firebase.storage();

export { storage, firebase as default };
```

Comment: Can you show us the way you initialised the firebase app?

Comment: @dileepkumarjami updated it with code for firebase initialize app.

Comment: Looks like import { snapShot, storage } from "firebase"; -- this import is directly from the firebase library but not from the exported storage constant from your separate firebase file. Try adding the import from the firebase file

Comment: @dileepkumarjami I finally understood what you meant, tried it out. still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. figured it out. it was a simple dumb typo.

had to change this:

```
const uploadTask = () =>
```

to this:

```
const uploadTask =
```